# Possible to change the compressibility of a fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

I have a question regarding the compressibility of a fluid. The isothermal compressibility of a fluid is defined as

$\beta=-\frac{1}{V} \frac{\partial V}{\partial P}$

where $V$ represents volume and $P$ represents pressure.

My question is:

Is it possible to change the isothermal compressibility of a fluid? Like adding some form of chemicals which will make the fluid more compressibile or less compressible?

Comment: Yes.  Just replace it by something else.

Comment: Yes. Material properties are often affected by changes in the surrounding fields (e.g., temperature, stress, electric field, magnetic field, material composition, light intensity, etc.).

Comment: Okay, thank you for your replies. I need to have the original fluid in place, because I would like to study a certain fluid. I can then change the surrounding fields, but do you know if there is some sort of chemical which will cause the original fluid to be less compressible (even at low chemical injection volume)?

Comment: Would the compressibility of the fluid change if we inject some chemical which increases the density of the fluid?